# MFC CString Format gives weird behaviour

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, c-strings

I am having a weird problem with `CString` I have the following code which gives an unexpected result:

```
CString sourcePath = _T("C:\\some\\path\\file.ext");
CString log;
log.Format(_T("Path = %s"), sourcePath);
```

the result string shows `Path = (null)`.

I am not sure what is going on under the hood there, I have tried casting the `sourcePath` to an `LPCTSTR` and got a valid pointer and when viewing the content of that memory address in the memory view window of MSVC everything seems valid.

this annoys me as I have tried the same method in previous projects and it worked pretty well.

Thanks.

P.S. Please, before people start commenting here asking about what is a `CString`, as it happened in an earlier post of mine, please check here first: [MSDN CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18he3sk6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Edit: sorry about the slash thingy.. and yes the original code does have double slashes..

Comment: This sample doesn't reproduce the problem here. Have you checked for buffer overflows that could affect sourcePath? Is this your literal code, or does other things happen in between the 3 lines you've shown?

Comment: @Erik, I just tested this with Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2008 and was unable to duplicate the problem as well.  There must be some other code going on in between.

Comment: Got the same problem. Oh, yes, I have some old projects with MFC ;) VS2012 and VS6 can reproduce this problem.
My format string was "some text %s, some text: %d, %d, %s text %s". First string was ok, but the second and third are not - only "(null)". So I divided this massive format string into two smaller and now it looks good. Third string was added without format. One %s per format string.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your sourcePath initialization. 
The character \ is a special character in C/C++. You should replace it with \ (double )
So the first line of code should be: CString sourcePath = _T("C:\\some\\path\\file.ext");

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As your MSDN CString link also mentions, you cannot pass the CString itself to the Format function.

Use:

```
  log.Format(_T("Path = %s"), sourcePath.GetString());
```

Comment: You misunderstood what article says. `"The call will fail if the string object itself is offered as a parameter to Format"` means that you cannot pass the object as an argument of the method invoked on it. Passing another `CString` object is perfectly fine.

Comment: You're entirely correct, I reacted to passing objects through ellipsis. Read up on the (ugly) trick MS used to make this work now.

Comment: again as I said in the original post I have tried casting it to an LPCTSTR and it didnt work, also tried wstring and had the same problem and the pointer seems valid

Comment: No. See article about CString "Big Brother helps you" - http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0073/

Answer (score 0):

The string "C:\some\path\file.ext" should be "C:\some\path\file.ext" - otherwise you will read control characters (\s \p \f) instead.

Comment: whoops the second string should have double slashes. And I see someone else has got the answer first.

Comment: yup sorry about that, actually I wrote the path there on the top of my head.. fixed now.

Comment: Hi - I wrote a little test app to look at your problem (if you are still experiencing this) and the code below is a work around to do the same thing - its probably not what you want as I imagine you want to solve the problem as opposed to work round it:

 // Incudes...
 #include <string>
 #include <stdio.h>

  std::string strSourcePath = "C:\\some\\path\\file.ext";
 char szFullPath[256];
 sprintf_s( szFullPath, sizeof(szFullPath), "Path = %s", strSourcePath.c_str() );
 CString log( szFullPath );
 
 - Sorry I had a few problems adding a code snippet.

Comment: Your original code works on a SDI MFC app auto generated through the wizard, so perhaps it may be worth doing that yourself and comparing the project settings to see whats different?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the MFC version and whether your app is built for win32 or x64, you might have to cast the CString:

```
log.Format(_T("Path = %s"), (LPCTSTR)sourcePath);
```